# Selenium autocomplete selection

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am in the URL: http://www.wiki-doctor.com.

I would like to type 'Nhi' in the autocomplete field id 'speciality' and select the first choice from the list, i tried this code below, no success:

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("speciality")).sendKeys("Nhi");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    List<WebElement> listItems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-autocomplete-input']"));
    listItems.get(0).click();
```

Cheers.

Comment: change it to driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".ui-autocomplete-input")); it works now, thanks all

Answer (score 0):

How did you build the xpath for autocomplete items? I can see that it is not relevant. Try another one, for example //ul[contains(@class,'ui-autocomplete')]/li/a

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("speciality")).sendKeys("Nhi");
driver.findElement(By.id("speciality")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
driver.findElement(By.id("speciality")).sendKeys(Keys.BACKSPACE);
```

Or a bit less memory consuming:

```
WebElement autocomplete = driver.findElement(By.id("speciality"));
autocomplete.sendKeys("Nhi");
autocomplete.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
autocomplete.sendKeys(Keys.BACKSPACE);
```

You might want to do a syntax check on that one as I am a little rusty with Webdriver and just typed this out of my head.

The key to this is to literally mimic the behaviour which a user without a mouse would do. That is:

1. Type text
2. Press the down-key
3. Press Enter

It is possible that the code will execute more rapidly than the website renders the dropdown. In this case you will have to use a WebDriver Wait.

```
new WebdriverWait().until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("ui-id-1")), 5);
```

Which gives:

```
WebElement autocomplete = driver.findElement(By.id("speciality"));
autocomplete.sendKeys("Nhi");
new WebdriverWait().until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("ui-id-1")), 5);
autocomplete.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
autocomplete.sendKeys(Keys.BACKSPACE);
```